# Show that if there are 15 points scattered inside a 1 unit square, then at least 3 of them can be covered by a square of side $1/5$

Tags: geometry, pigeonhole-principle

I have been trying to find a proper way to divide the square into smaller squares but nothing seems to be working so far, that is, trying to apply in a straight forward way the pidgeonhole principle. I tried dividing the square into rectangles but that didn't seem to work either (14 rectangles of sides $1/7\times 1/2$). Could this be solved by contradiction? Any suggestions?

Comment: Must the sides of candidate squares be axes-aligned?

Comment: Since the problem didn't specifically stated it, I supposed they don't have to.

Comment: Makes it much more difficult...

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Unless I'm misunderstanding, $\{(\frac{a}{4}, \frac{b}{2}) : 0 \leq a \leq 4, 0 \leq b \leq 2\}$ avoids this type of covering...

Comment: Yes, perhaps the professor made a mistake when he transcripted the problem. Could it be possible that it was $2/5$ instead of $1/5$? Either way, I was also unsure that the problem was correctly stated.

Comment: @NotAMathematician I guess that instead of **a side 1/5** should be 
**... a square of area 1/5**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I simply don't see it:

[image]

or better:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true.  Place two points at each of the dots in the figure.  The side of the inner square is $\frac {\sqrt 2}4$, greater than the diagonal of a square of side $\frac 15$.  The distance from a corner to a corner of the center square is greater yet.  By expanding the central square this construction works for $16$ points up to a distance of $\frac{\sqrt 3-1}{\sqrt 2} \approx 0.51764$, so we are not even close.
[image]